# ASP.NET Core is not available on internet

Tags: asp.net, api, iis

After I deployed an ASP.NET Core API page, I can browse to in on the host machine (Azure VM), but when I tried on a different computer, it displays 404 page. Is there something to setup on the VM itself to allow internet. I have another MVC page has been working fine for years.
I downloaded Postman to the VM and verified it worked fine on the VM, but not on my PC or any other devices on Internet.

Comment: Describe how you deployed it such as IIS site bindings.

Comment: please post more information about 404 error.